# Работа с метками категорий в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, архитектура

Хотелось бы узнать, как устроена архитектура построения таблиц для работы с метками (как в stackowerflow)!
Например, есть таблицы Posts и Stacks, и у поста может быть отношение с метками ("Java","Spring") из таблицы Stacks. Оптимально ли создать таблицу Post2Stack и в ней иметь внешние ключи PostId и StackId?

Answer (score 1):

Да.
Если вы создаёте данные через `many-to-many` таблицу,

- **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** делаете первичный ключ через эти 2 поля,
- **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** на каждое поле делаете внешний ключ к соответствующей таблице,
  вы получаете на выходе корректные точные данные

Answer (score 0):

Да. Описанный вами вариант является оптимальный.

При этом в таблице Post2Stack не нужен дополнительный суррогатный первичный ключ, а сама пара PostId, StackId будет хорошим естественным первичным ключом.